# Algorithm to rank the simplicity of a random name

Tags: linguistics

I have been looking for a name for a new project. I want the name to have available domains and social media handles. For months, all those I can think of are taken.

So I generated a list of names with at least a consonant and a vowel and checked if the domains are available (which is very fast). I have about a million possible names.

I would like to sort them by some rank of simplicity. "Aaazq" would be close to the bottom, "Cawel" would be close to the top. I thought of the CVC structure (Consonant-Vowel-Consonant) and wonder if some more sophisticated algorithm exists. I searched for "sonority" but it has a different meaning in linguistics.

How can I automatically rank the simplicity of a random name?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would judge simplicity as compared to a target language, say English. Something that is 'simple' in English might not be 'simple' in German or Korean, as these languages have very different phonological structures.

I would recommend the following:

- collect some data of the language you are using. Just get some novels from Project Gutenberg, for example, or newspaper articles. Whatever you can easily get hold of.
- now generate n-grams from this: all sequences of two (bigrams) or three (trigrams) letters. Turn this into a frequency list, so that common n-grams are at the top of the list with a high frequency.
- turn your suggested name into n-grams. Count how many times the respective n-gram occurs in your frequency list, and take the average or median of the result

Your examples would do as follows:

- `aa aa az zq`: "aa" is rare ("aardvark") "az" a bit more common ("glaze", "raze"), and "zq" would not exist. So, not a very high score.
- `ca aw we el`: all of these are fairly common in English words, so a reasonably high score.

You could also add a dummy `#` at the beginning and the end, so in your first example you'd get `#a`, which is fine, as many English words start with "a", but the final `q#` bombs out, as there's only words such as "Iraq" which end in a "q".

You can obviously do the same for other languages.

Also, you can reverse the process in a way, and pick random n-grams from your frequency list to generate names: by picking higher-frequency n-grams you will make sure the name is a good match with the phonological structure of your target language.

Note for pedants: I use *phonological structure*, but it's really its representation in the spelling system that we're dealing with here.

Comment: I think this is a great approach and it is modular to a target language, or sub-literature such as the [Oxford Children's Corpus](https://www.sketchengine.eu/oxford-childrens-corpus/).